# Tricky recursive function 007

Tags: c, recursion

Elo, I got this code snippet from an old exam. It's tricky and I need some help figuring out how it prints "007".

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* Desmond Llewelyns */
int M(int Q);
int main(void)
 {

   M(9);
   return 0;
 }
int M(int Q)
 {
   if(Q>1) 
     if(M(Q-1)==0)
       printf("%03d\n", Q);

   return Q-6;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand how the function ever reaches "return Q-6;

Answer (score 8):

It is pretty simple.

Number will be printed only if `M(Q-1)` returns `0` and that happens when value of `Q` is `7`.

And about the zeros, it is because you are asking printf to print the number in 3 positions printing zeros in the begining. `printf("%03d\n", Q);` Read more [here](http://www.codingunit.com/printf-format-specifiers-format-conversions-and-formatted-output).

Comment: Perhaps you should explain the formatting as well. It may not be obvious that the third digit is the 7.

Answer (score 3):

M(Q-1) returns 0 when Q is equal to 7

printf("%03d\n", Q) will print the 7 to 3 positions resulting in 007

Comment: This only addresses the 7, and not "007".

Comment: @TravisJ:- Is it OK now but I thought that OP knew that..and I dont deserve a downvote for that!!! :(